# document.ready() not fired in window opened from addon popup

Tags: jquery

I am new to addon creation and not very experienced in javascript and jquery. 
I would like to create a GUI in a popup window that I create using a button in the addon browser-action popup.
I could manage to have the window opened and loaded from the button but the JQuery document.ready() in the new window is never fired .
I put below the code of the various files of the addon.

MANIFEST

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "testaddon",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Just for testing ideas",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "traducteur RU FR",
      "default_popup" :"popup/popup.html"

   },


  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content_scripts/testaddon.js"]
    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "dictFile.txt"
  ]

}
```

**popup/popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css"/>
  </head>
  <body style="width: 500px; height: 400px;">
      <h1>A popup title</h1>
      <button id="interface" >Open window</button>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

**popup/popupejs**

```
function openWindow() {
    var newWindow = window.open(browser.extension.getURL("popup/interface.html"), 
                                 null, "height=600,width=600,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no");  
    newWindow.document.write(popHtml);
    newWindow.close();
}

var but=document.getElementById('interface');
but.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
```

**popup/interface.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="interface.css"/>
     <script>src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"</script>
<script src="interface.js"></script>
  </head>
<body style="width: 500px; height: 400px;">
 <div>
 <h1>hello</h1>
   <fieldset>
    <label for="target">Type Something:</label>
    <input id="target" type="text">
  </fieldset> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

popup/interface.js**

```
alert("a trivial alert");
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("document ready");
});
```

The result of all this is that only the first alert (trivial) is triggered. 
Thank you for help.

UPDATE FOR INFO

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  alert('document ready javascript');
});
```

The above code without JQuery works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in:

```
<script>src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"</script>
```

, change it to:

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if it works, pls upvote and/or accept the answer :)